# How to properly use a data-services in Polymer

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have custom element `<data-service>` and I have several custom elements which uses data from `<data-service>` (search, add, edit elements). How to properly use a `<data-service>`?

1. Many objects. Add `<data-service>` in every custom element and use bindings and listeners to manipulate data.
2. Singleton. Add `<data-service/>` in root (index.html) and use like app.$.dataService for calling functions and properties (I can't understand how can I add listeners)

Answer (score -1):

You could use [Polymer Behaviors](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors.html)

[Demo video](https://youtu.be/YrlmieL3Z0k)

Comment: In fact this is "1. Many objects", but without duplicate code? Can you help me with "behavior with ajax calls"?

Comment: May be this is not `Polymer` style, but I decide to do so: create 'service' custom element with functions receives ES6 Promises. Add this in application root and work with service like app.$.service.find().then("bin response to custom element").